# FlotJS: Showing only part of the plotted data

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a real-time flot chart showing bitrate values that are updated within an interval. I perform an API call to the backend to get the last 3 minutes and plot them.

Now, I want to add panable capabilities to the chart, so the user can be able to move backwards in the time. I can correctly set the limits to the `xaxis` `panRange` (first value and last value received). The idea is to load the page showing the last 3 minutes, but you can go back. Simple.

The problem is that flot is plotting and showing every value I get from the backend and I cannot find any configuration/option to specify the "visible" range.

I have though using the zoom to delimit the visible area of the chart, but it will require to recalculate the zoom on each data update.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`xaxis.min`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) and [`xaxis.max`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) options to specify the visible range:

```
var options = {
    xaxis: {
      min: 3,
      max: 5
    }
}
```

[This JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrbsfb50/) has an example of setting the `min` and `max` values to limit the visible range of data with basic zoom and pan functionality.